# jquery slider for nopcommerce 2.65 with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I am working on latest nopCommerce V 2.65. I would like to provide a jquery slider which moves on arrow key as well as on mouse click on side arrow.

Plesae provide me any link or demo code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Check with these guys: http://www.nop-templates.com/p/4/nop-anywhere-sliders - I think that functionality is there, but if not, post it as a feature request on their board, and they'll usually add it within a short time, if it's a popular request.

Comment: Hi Carole, Thanks for your help but it requires some money to be paid and our customer is not ready for that so I am looking for any free solution if it is there.

Comment: I hear where you're coming from. Think about it this way; how many hours of labor would you have to pay for to get the same option, and then how many more hours would you have to devote to ongoing maintenance? The best way to make that call is to look at your overall billing on this client, and see if you'll make a better profit by not having to pay dev hours. Good luck - I'll post a link if I come across anything else!

Comment: Thanks Carole for your support!! :)